# How to decompress IDAT compressed data

Tags: python, image-processing, png, zlib, deflate

i wrote some python code to extract each chunk of a PNG image , i've tried with 3 different images and it works perfectly , it also matches perfectly what's displayed in https://rameshvarun.github.io/binary-inspector/png/ when i open the corresponding file , my script stores each chunk in a dict with the size of the data of each chunck (converted into an int) the type of the chunk (name , ie IDAT for an IDAT chunk) the data (everything excluding the CRC and the size and the type) and the CRC as keys

i tried using the deflate method  from the zlib library using zlib.decompress
on the data key of each data key of each chunk , also tried adding the CRC but i keep getting the error zlib.error: Error -5 while decompressing data: incomplete or truncated stream

Comment: png has many compression scemes, only one of them is gzip the current line. Read a complete PNG format document

Comment: @rioV8 i did read several documents explaining the compression of PNG IDAT chunks , all of them said the deflate algorithm was used to compress data , and i also verified it was the one used to compress the files i tried to decompress wich was the case

Comment: Don't forget there's an initial byte that tells you the filter method being used.

Comment: @MarkSetchell In order to even see the initial byte on each row, you need to first make it through decompression successfully.

Comment: @rioV8 PNG doesn't use the gzip format at all. It always uses the zlib format for compression, and never any other compression method. What can vary is the pixel filtering that precedes the compression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data from the IDAT chunks need to be concatenated into a single binary stream for decompression. Or at least decompressed as if it were concatenated, using `zlib.decompressobj`. That data is a single deflate stream, regardless of how it was split into IDAT chunks.

Comment: that's exactly what i did , when i used zlib.decompress it was a the whole data part of the IDAT chunk , including the header (excluding the CRC) , it was a single byte stream

Comment: i first got the raw data from the image with open and  .read() then made it readable and easier to process by getting the hex values using .hex() , then extracted each chunk , then tried to decompress the data of the first IDAT chunk by re-turning it into a byte hex object with zlib.decompress(bytes.fromhex(liste_chunk["IDAT"][0]["data"]))

Comment: You're saying "the first IDAT chunk", so there must be more than one IDAT chunk. If you did what you're saying, "tried to decompress the data of the first IDAT chunk", then you will certainly get the incomplete stream error. Because it's an incomplete stream. You need to concatenate the extracted data from _all_ of the IDAT chunks together. Then decompress that. You say "that's exactly what i did", but then go on to explain how you did not do that.

Comment: oh sorry i mussunderstood i though you were talking about concatenating only the data of the first Idat chunk but now i understand , thanks a lot for the explaination

Comment: It works ! no error , sucessfully decompressed , thanks a lot! it wasn't mentionned than i had to concatenate in all of the docs i read.

Comment: It does say that in the PNG specification, https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-PNG-20031110/#11IDAT, "There may be multiple IDAT chunks; if so, they shall appear consecutively with no other intervening chunks. The compressed datastream is then the concatenation of the contents of the data fields of all the IDAT chunks."

Comment: yea i already went to this website but the page i was at didnt specify that , also now than i have it decompressed do you have any idea how could i get the scanlines out of it ? Im trying mainly to extract the rgb values

Comment: _Read that specification._ It will tell you format of rows and how to unfilter the bytes in each row to get the pixel values.

Comment: i think i shouldnt have a problem with filtering since according to the specification 0 equals no filtering but in https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-PNG-20031110/ at 7.2 Scanlines and it did say how those scanlines were structured but i couldn't find were the scanlines started and where they ended , i also took a look at http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.1/png-1.1-pdg.html also in the scanlines section but it also didn't mention were they started and ended , i can't deny i'm struggling to understand in detail those docs cause i'm not native.

Comment: If it's RGB eight bits, then the bytes after the zero filter byte in each row are R, G, and B. If it's RGBA, then those bytes are R, G, B, and A.

Comment: Thanks a lot , that clarrifies a lot of things ^^ , but there's one thing i'm missing , do each scanline have a filter byte or is there 1 filter byte for the whole decompressed data?

Comment: Sorry if i ask foolish questions btw ^^'

Comment: Each row starts with a filter byte.

Comment: so basically each row's lenght is image width * bit depth +1 right ?

Comment: because that's what they said in http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.1/png-1.1-pdg.html

Comment: No. You need the bit depth _and_ the color type to compute the size of a pixel. Which is measured in bytes, not bits.

Comment: oh , ok , i understand now , thank you so much for the explainations! ^^